# Spring Boot - OAuth2 - Resource Server - GitHub as Authorization Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, github-api

I'm developing a Spring Boot REST API and I'd like to use GitHub as an Authorization Server for my Resource Server. I already achieved this with Google using https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs to verify the bearer tokens. However, I can't find the same for GitHub.

Is it possible to use GitHub as an Authorization Server (to verify tokens in my server), or only as a client?

If this is not possible, are there other options besides Google and Microsoft?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least to ways to achieve multi-tenant scenarios (cases where you have more than just one users identity providers):

- configure your resource server with a custom [`JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/2b852a95fcf8ca849eaf8c546b2be5b2d18dfc37/webmvc/spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/config/synchronised/ServletSecurityBeans.java#L223) or [`ReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/2b852a95fcf8ca849eaf8c546b2be5b2d18dfc37/webflux/spring-addons-webflux-jwt-resource-server/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/config/reactive/ReactiveSecurityBeans.java#L163)
- identity provider federation: use an authorization-server which will federate all other identity providers

If all of your identity providers issue JWT access tokens, first option is dead simple. Have a look at [this tutorial to get started in minutes](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication).

Otherwise, and unfortunately this is the case for Google and Github which issue opaque access-tokens (not JWTs), you can consider Keycloak which supports federation for most common identities (Facebook, Google, Github, etc.). Tutorial above still applies, with a single entry in issuers configuration: your Keycloak instance.

Spring Authorization Server is also an option you might consider: it doesn't come with a UI (login, registration, clients administration, ...) or a database, but you don't really need that for just identity federation.